# SE Android app for tablet has bad formatting on feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

The lines wrap so much on v1.0.85 that only a few items can be displayed.

Edit: This is on the world's most low end tablet, Azpen A727.

Screenshots of the old:

[image: old feed]

and new, showing loss of quality

[image: new feed]

Comment: I assumed 1.0.85 is the newest version you're using. If it's incorrect, please edit it. I also add "Android tablet" as a generic info, but if possible, include the tablet model to help debugging.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct on the version.  I added the tablet type.

Comment: Same here with Nexus 9 on latest version of everything.

Comment: Also on Galaxy Tab 8.4 with 1.0.85. Pretty annoying, makes Feed extremely uncomfortable.

Comment: Almost 7 months and this hasn't been looked at...?

Comment: @ShadowWizard then StackExchange should pull it from the Google Play store.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It should still be pulled in that case.  (Abandoned = pull it; not maintaining = pull it)

Comment: It was last updated September 16th of this year.

Comment: @ThomasWard I strongly disagree that this app should be pulled just because of this feed formatting issue. Every other part of this very useful app seems to work fine. FYI  - App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-T550
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (T550XXU1BPK1)

Comment: I like the app overall. This seems like an easy fix, especially since it used to be ok.  Don't know why they've ignored it.

Comment: Just a note that I'm looking into this. It's a lot harder to solve than I had hoped. We use GridLayouts on the tablet feed view, with the Hot Questions Container and "EARLIER TODAY" date as full-width spans while everything else is supposed to go 2 to a line -- All the quick changes I've tried to get the feed items to display 2 to a line correctly on smaller width tablets make the feed fail on larger screens, so it's a delicate fix. I'm working on this and have a repro of the issue, though.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi As of this morning it looks good again.  Not sure how to accept / close this kind of meta question.  Do you post an answer?

Comment: @OrganicMarble you could post an answer with info like version that fixed the issue and providing the screenshot. That doesn't prevent the devs to post official answer, so it's safe.

Comment: I wonder why they don't use a single column layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest update (1.0.93) appears to have significantly improved the formatting on the feed.

[image]