# Very narrow columns in Feed display

Tags: bug, android-app

The attached screenshot says it all. It's like that regardless of the screen orientation, and it's been that way ever since I installed the app.

Thanks,
Mike Waters

[image: Display bug]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-T550

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (T550XXU1BPK1)

Comment: I see this is a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278440/358799 from last year. Please delete this post and I'll edit that.