# Portrait view messed up on a tablet

Tags: bug, android-tablet-app

This is not a duplicate of [SE Android app for tablet has bad formatting on feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278440/se-android-app-for-tablet-has-bad-formatting-on-feed), as while that's the same issue, it was fixed in version 1.0.93; this is a fresh regression in 1.0.95. The team prefers that users file new bug reports for regressions.

Massive gaps between items

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-P585

  - OS Version: 7.0 (P585JXU2BQF1)

[image: enter image description]

Comment: Do the duplicate posts cover your issue, or does it look different for you? If it looks different could you add screenshots to your post?

Comment: Thanks, I've added a screen shot

Comment: Awesome. I've voted to reopen as this isn't a RTL issue after all like the duplicate targets, and is an android tablet app issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SE Android app for tablet has bad formatting on feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278440/se-android-app-for-tablet-has-bad-formatting-on-feed)

Comment: @Somewhat While that's the same issue, it was fixed in 1.0.93. This pertains to 1.0.95, so this is a fresh issue. The team prefers that users file new bug reports if a fresh issue arises, so this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog I honestly don't see that it was "fixed" in 1.0.93. Yes, it was improved, but not necessarily fixed. The expected layout is a grid with the width fully extends like the old version on the linked dupe.