# SE app looks weird on mobile device

Tags: bug, design, android-app

I have been using SE sites (mainly SO) on my desktop computer and on my Samsung S4 mini mobile phone for years. It works well on of both devices. Recently I got a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 9.7, and the SE App looks like this on it:

[image]

There are 2 columns, which is not my favorite, but okay. But the text in each entry in the columns is wrapped much more often than necessary. It does not only look ugly, it's actually hard to read this way.

Please fix that: make the actual column width adapt to the available width. And if possible, make configurable whether 1 or 2 columns are shown.

BTW: OS is LineageOS 15.1, but this should not matter.

Comment: You know that the app is absolutely braked for development, and there are no plans to resume it, because SE wants people using the mobile browser version instead, right?

Comment: @Nij: No, I didn't know that. I really like the app...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SE Android app for tablet has bad formatting on feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278440/se-android-app-for-tablet-has-bad-formatting-on-feed). It's a tablet-only bug.